# Need to execute the unix shell script in background and call it in bashrc

Tags: bash, unix

I have written a Shell script in which a `curl` command generates authentication token. But this token expires every 30 minutes. So I dont want execute this script manually everytime.

Two things I want to do here:

1. I want to schedule this script in backend.
2. I want to call this script in `.bashrc`

Please suggest.

Comment: Suggestion 1. Do some search on the web. Suggestion 2. After doing suggestion 1, try some code and if you still don't get it, put your code following this guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 1. Use your preferred scheduler 2. call the code from .bashrc

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a new `crontab` entry (`crond` should running) :

```
$ crontab -e
```

then

```
*/20 * * * * /full/path/to/script.sh
```

it will run every 20 mn. For the `~/.bashrc` part, I don't get you.

Comment: where do i see the result of it ?

Comment: Cron sends you email if there is output from the job, but the usual solution is to write the job in such a way that it saves its results to a file.